# Where is the source code in Android for setting the homescreen background image?

Tags: android, homescreen

I'm browsing the Android source code, but can't find where is the source code for setting the homescreen background image.

Like when you press and hold the homescreen, and you get a dialog saying "Choose wallpaper from", then select Gallery, then select an image, and it gets placed.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Launcher2/src/com/android/launcher2/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.WallpaperChooser.java.
```

it's in same package with Launcher.java

```
2.LiveWallpaperListActivity.java
```

/packages/wallpapers/LivePicker/src/com/android/wallpaper/livepicker

```
3.Photographs.java
```

/packages/apps/Gallery3D/src/com/cooliris/media